# Segue only performed upon selecting another table row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, segue

I am currently writing an app that downloads the RSS feed of a wordpress website and displays it in a table view. When you tap on an item in the list, it goes to the details view and displays the content. However, I have a strange issue with the segue to get from the Table View to the Detail View whereby the segue is not performed immediately after tapping on a row, but only when another row is tapped afterwards. The content displayed is that of the first selection.

For example, if i click row 1, it is highlighted but there is no transition. Nothing happens until I click another row, at which point the segue is performed to the detail view which shows the information for row 1. I have the following methods to perform the segue:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   _selectedFeedItem = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
}
```

and

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DetailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.selectedFeedItem = _selectedFeedItem;
}
```

I am very new to objective-C and iPhone app development so apologies if this is an obvious issue. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

(deselect)

You need...

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

(select)

Comment: @joecarver haha, no worries :D